# How can I test a stdin script "live", that normally a program interacts with in the background?

Tags: python, stdout, stdin

my script is as follows:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import MySQLdb

if __name__=="__main__":

dbcon = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", port=3306, user="user", passwd="passwd", db="db")
dbcur = dbcon.cursor()

deliveryCount = 0
bounceBadMailbox = 0
bounceInactiveAccount = 0
bouncePolicyRelated = 0
bounceSpamRelated = 0
bounceQuotaIssues =0

while True:
    #type, timeLogged,timeQueued,orig,rcpt,orcpt,dsnAction,dsnStatus,dsnDiag,dsnMta,bounceCat,srcType,srcMta,dlvType,dlvSourceIp,dlvDestinationIp,dlvEsmtpAvailable,dlvSize,vmta,jobId,envId,queue,vmtaPool
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    fwrite = open("debug.log","w")
    fwrite.write("in true loop")

    logList = line.split(',')

    bounceType = logList[0]
    bounceCategory = logList[10]
    emailAddress = logList[4]
    jobId = logList[19]

    if bounceType == 'd':
        deliveryCount += 1
        dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET pmta_delivered = pmta_delivered + %d WHERE id = %d', (deliveryCount,jobId))
        dbcon.commit()

    elif bounceType == 'b':
        if bounceCategory == 'bad-mailbox':
            bounceBadMailbox +=1
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE list_users SET status = %s, modified_date=NOW() WHERE email=%s', ('b',emailAddress))
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET bad_mailbox = bad_mailbox + %d WHERE id = %d', (bounceBadMailbox,jobId))
            dbcon.commit()

        elif bounceCategory =='inactive-account':
            bounceInactiveAccount +=1
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE list_users SET status = %s, modified_date=NOW() WHERE email=%s', ('i',emailAddress))
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET inactive_account = inactive_account + %d WHERE id = %d', (bounceInactiveAccount,jobId))
            dbcon.commit()

        elif bounceCategory =='policy-related':
            bounceInactiveAccount +=1
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE list_users SET status = %s, modified_date=NOW() WHERE email=%s', ('p',emailAddress))
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET policy_related = policy_related + %d WHERE id = %d', (bouncePolicyRelated,jobId))
            dbcon.commit()

        elif bounceCategory =='spam-related':
            bounceInactiveAccount +=1
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE list_users SET status = %s, modified_date=NOW() WHERE email=%s', ('s',emailAddress))
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET spam_related = spam_related + %d WHERE id = %d', (bounceSpamRelated,jobId))
            dbcon.commit()

        elif bounceCategory =='quota-issues':
            bounceInactiveAccount +=1
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE list_users SET status = %s, modified_date=NOW() WHERE email=%s', ('q',emailAddress))
            dbcur.execute('UPDATE campaign_stat_delivered SET quota_issues = quota_issues + %d WHERE id = %d', (bounceQuotaIssues,jobId))
            dbcon.commit()


fwrite = open("debug2.log","w")
fwrite.write("out of true loop")

dbcon.close()
```

I'm not getting any results whatsoever, and it's taking me a really long time to debug, because I have to modify the script, restart my program that feeds into stdin, and then try my line of code.

Is there a way I can do:

```
python mystdinscript.py
```

and see actual results? ...i.e. what do I need to do to create a python script that can feed into an actively running stdin script?

as I currently stand, my program pipes into this script, and I don't see any results--so It's extremely hard to debug.

Comment: On linux, you could use something like the `tee` utility to observe the communications.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to see your output is to set `fwrite` to stdout:

```
#fwrite = open(...)
fwrite = sys.stdout
```

This will print the results to your screen instead of to the file.